# Cannot change screen brightness on ubuntu 16.04 LTS or connect to WIFI

Tags: 16.04, wireless, updates, brightness

I have been running ubuntu 16.04 LTS for about a month now, and I have had no problems. I ran an update this morning, and now, I cannot change screen brightness. I am getting no feedback from the keyboard, and there isn't even an option to change screen brightness from the settings menu. My wifi networks also are not connecting or even showing up.

This is strange because these were not issues before I ran an update this morning. Has anyone had issues with this update or have some suggestions?

Thanks!